QUERY function with multiple conditions using time frame
I have this query that I am trying to add a condition to to filter out the results of a report given a time frame (time frame in my sheet is N2 and N3)
What I have now is the following and it works like a charm:
=QUERY('Report'!$A$2:$I; "Select B Where A = '"&$B28&"'");"Nothing to show")

No I want to add a condition to filter out only the results given my time period in N2 (start date) and N3 (end date). My dates in the reports are in column D. I did the following but it's not working:
=QUERY('Report'!$A$2:$I; "Select B Where A = '"&$B12&"';Select D where D >= date '"&$N$2&"' and D <= date '"&$N$3&"'");"Nothing to show")
What am I doing wrong?

Your query syntax is wrong. Try the following QUERY() formula-
=QUERY('Report'!$A$2:$I; "Select B Where A = '"&$B12&"' and D>= date '" &TEXT(N2,"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' and D<= date '" & TEXT(N3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",1)


I just used this using dd-mm-yyyy format (because that is my date format) and I get an error.
=QUERY('MASTER Pending Opps'!$A$2:$I; "Select B Where A = '"&$B12&"' and D>= date '" &TEXT(N2 ,"dd-mm-yyyy")& "' and D<= date '" & TEXT(N3 ,"dd-mm-yyyy") & "'",1)

@A.Be Did you with "yyyy-mm-dd" because google-sheet use that format?

I actually tried both formats and they both give me an error

I just typed everything in manually and with a slight change in the formula, it's working now:
=QUERY('MASTER Report'!$A$2:$I; "Select B Where A = '"&$B12&"' and D>= date '"&TEXT(N2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D<= date '"&TEXT(N3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
